# I have a set with two vectors in $R^3$. What method should I use to find the vectors orthogonal to both in the original set?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

There are so many different methods I've found on SE and through Matlab, and they're all giving me different results.

Specifically, I have {v1} = (1,2,1) and {v2} = (2,1,0) in set S. What is the method to find {v3} vectors that are orthogonal to both v1 and v2?

I'm preparing for a final and I'm trying to find a flexible method for many cases. The answer I got for above was v3 = {1,-2,3} but different methods are returning different results.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is an infinite number of vectors that are perpendicular to two other vectors—in fact they form a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. It shouldn’t be all that surprising that different methods choose a different vector from this space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Your answer should be a non-zero scalar multiple of the $v_3$ that you provided since $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not parallel to each other.

Method $1$:

- Compute the cross product of $v_1$ and $v_2$, that will give you a valid solution.

Method $2$:

- Solve the linear system $v_1^Tx=0$ and $v_2^Tx=0$ by reducing the system say to REF. You will obtain multiple solution, of which all of them are scalar multiple of $v_3$.

Either method should be fine.

Comment: Thank you! The cross product made it all come together. Had some issues with positive/negative values in my method, but I forgot about the +, -, + property of the cross product.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

- Compute the planes orthogonal to both of your vectors.

A plane orthogonal to the vector $(a,b,c)$ has the equation $ax + by + cz + d = 0, \forall d \in \mathbb{R}$

- Compute the intersection of the two planes by replacing the first plane equation in the second one